# The type name {myUserControl} does not exist in the type {myNamespace.myNamespace}

Tags: c#, namespaces, designer, subclass

I have a problem (obviously the question :)

I have a project--  MyProject... hence the rest of the project uses a default of any classes as namespace "MyProject"... no problem.

In my project, I created a custom user control that has many other controls on it (label, textboxes, etc).  So, that class is ALSO within the default namespace of "MyProject".  All compiles no problem.  Just to confirm scope visibility, on this user control, I made sure that the DESIGNER code and the Code-Behind (My code) are BOTH within the same "MyProject" namespace (they are), AND they are both respectively PUBLIC PARTIAL CLASS MyUserControl.

Now the issue.  I create a simple form (also in namespace "MyProject" by default).  From the toolbox, the "MyUserControl" exists so I drag it onto MyNewForm.  Drag/Drop is fine.

Save all, compile, fail...  The Designer is adding an extra "MyProject" reference thus making it appear that the user control is actually located at  MyProject.MyProject.MyUserControl .. instead of MyProject.MyUserControl.

As soon as I manually remove the extra "MyProject.", save and compile, all is fine.  However, if I re-edit the form, change something, M$ changes it back to the original "MyProject.MyUserControl" reference.

All that being said, here are the snippets from my project...

```
namespace MyProject
{
   partial class MyNewForm
   {
      ...
      private void InitializeComponent()
      {
         // THIS is the line that has the extra "MyProject." reference
         // when I manually remove it, all works perfectly
         this.MyUserControl1 = new MyProject.MyUserControl();
      }
   }


   private MyUserControl MyUserControl1;

}
```

---

Then, in the MyUserControl definition I have...

```
namespace MyProject
{
   public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
   ...
}
```

and from the MyUserControl via the Designer...

```
namespace MyProject
{
   public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
   ...

}
```

Thanks for the help...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What the designer is doing is ok.

--> You have somehere in your project a namespace called `MyProject.MyProject`.

(Try finding it in "Class View")

Comment: Also happens, when You have class in some namespace with the same name as it's namespace.

Answer (score 13):

**PS. to anyone who has same problem but has not found any solution...**

Assuming you have created a new WindowsFormApplication;

1. Create a new WindowsFormApplication project using same name as its solution name.
2. The default pre-created Form name comes called "Form1". And change its name same as the project name.
3. Add new UserControl class into the project.
4. Build/Rebuild the project and check the usercontrol is located at Toolbox.
5. Drag the usercontrol onto the form and start debugging.

> - Error: The type name 'userControlName' does not exist in the type 'projectName.FormName'

I had research on net for any solution but couldn't come up with any answer...

But if you change the form name any other different from the project name, it'll be resolved.

If you insist on that the form name and project name has to be same depending on your project needs, a custom DLL could be created and use the usercontrol in it.

Then to use as a control, add the DLL file to "ToolBox" using "Choose Items..."

Finally it is going to be ready to use.

**PS2. struggling the same problem for hours, this is the solution I found.**

Comment: I've run into a similar issue. For me, it was a class with the same name of the namespace. Drove me crazy but thanks to this answer I found it.

Answer (score 3):

The Namespace Name and Class Name need to be different. The code generated by adding the WCF automatically references the Namespace but if the Class name is the same as the Namespace name, the generated code looks at the Class and nothing will compile.

Answer (score 1):

Name of User Control and Form are same. Using different names will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Since this was a top search result when I had this error, just want to post my cause and solution.

- I had two projects within a solution, sharing a 'common' class file which was added as a link.
- I added a second 'helper' class file as a link, used its code within the first, and got the error.

The problem was I had not added the second 'helper' class as a link in both projects.

So the other project had an updated 'common' class, but no knowledge of the 'helper' class it now used.

Note to self: pay more attention to the project column of the error list :)

Answer (score 0):

Just encountered this where I had a MasterPage that had an explicit

```
<%@ Import Namespace="MyNamespace" %>
```

in the .master file

Answer (score 0):

This also happens when you use different pages but with same name. In my case I had created "Grants.xsd" dataset and "Grants.aspx" page. Somehow they got in conflict resulting in this error.

**You can easily trouble shoot this by hovering over the culprit keyword (class name) and in Visual Studio 2013, it will tell you exactly where the conflict is.**